# Replace returns 2 of the same value?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, richtextbox

I have a question on why this is happening. First, I'll explain what is going on. I am finding a line in a `RichTextBox` and taking a `Split` value and replacing it with the same value but with a decimal limit. Here is what my file looks like:

```
J6   INT-00113G  227.905  174.994    180   SOIC8
J3   INT-00113G  227.905  203.244    180   SOIC8
U13  EXCLUDES    242.210  181.294    180   QFP128
```

### BUT for some reason I am getting this when I try to replace and output it back out... *(the numbers appear twice in both the 3rd and 4th columns)*

```
J6   INT-00113G  227.91227.91   174.99174.99     180   SOIC8
J3   INT-00113G  227.91227.91   203.24203.24     180   SOIC8
U13  EXCLUDES    242.21242.21   181.29181.29     180   QFP128
```

***AND HERE IS MY CODE... WHAT IS THE ERROR TO MAKE IT DO THIS?***

```
string[] myLines = placementTwoRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
foreach (string line in myLines)
{
    // Matches the entire line.
    Match theMatch = Regex.Match(line, @".*");

    if (theMatch.Success)
    {
        // Stores the matched value in string output.
        string output = theMatch.Value;

        // Replaces tabs and extra space with only 1 space delimiter
        output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\s+", " ");

        // Splits the specified regex into two different regexs.
        var componentItem = output.Split(' ');

        double d1 = Convert.ToDouble(componentItem[2]);
        double d2 = Convert.ToDouble(componentItem[3]);
        double round1 = Math.Round(d1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        double round2 = Math.Round(d2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        componentItem[2] = Regex.Replace(componentItem[2], @".*", round1.ToString());
        componentItem[3] = Regex.Replace(componentItem[3], @".*", round2.ToString());

        // Sets the RichTextBox to the string output.
        newPl2ItemsRichTextBox.AppendText(componentItem[0] + "   " + componentItem[1] + "   " + componentItem[2] +
            "   " + componentItem[3] + "   " + componentItem[4] + "   " + componentItem[5] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What happens when you remove `regex.replace(...)` and just use `compontentItem[2] = round1.ToString();` ?

Comment: is the whole purpose of this to simply round the two numbers?

Comment: @c0deNinja: yes but there is some difficulties that I have already cleared up beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing all this, simply do your split, since you know index 2 and 3 contain your numbers...  simply do something like:

newPl2ItemsRichTextBox.AppendText(componentItem[0] + "   " + componentItem[1] + "   " + Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(componentItem[2]), 2) + "   " + Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(componentItem[3]), 2) + "   " + componentItem[4] + "   " + componentItem[5] + "\n");

Avoid all the other steps, just split and print.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression ".*" hits two matches:
Try out following code to reproduce:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@".*");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches("  227.905  ");
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", match);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Matches are:
"  227.905  " and
""

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:
In 227.905 there is a point in the middle which probably lets the replace function work on 227 and 905. That's why the rounded numbers are inserted twice.

Comment: Almost, yes there are two matches, but not those you mentioned. See answer below.